# FLUTTER - Gráfico de pizza com a cor preta sobreposta as demais

Tags: flutter, gráfico

*Sou iniciante em Flutter*
Estou desenvolvendo um dashboard em Flutter, o qual gostaria de montar um gráfico donuts para demonstrar a quantidade de motores e seus respectivos estados.
Segue o código do componente:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../constants/estilo.dart';
import '../../constants/global.dart';
import '../../controller/navegacao.dart';
import '../../provider/dados_provider.dart';

class GraficoMotores extends StatefulWidget {
  const GraficoMotores({super.key});

  @override
  State<GraficoMotores> createState() => _GraficoMotoresState();
}

class _GraficoMotoresState extends State<GraficoMotores> {
  /// Declaração dos providers
  late DadosMotoresProvider dadosMotores;
  late EstadoMotoresProvider estadoMotoresProvider;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Buscando dados nos providers
    dadosMotores = context.watch<DadosMotoresProvider>();
    estadoMotoresProvider = context.watch<EstadoMotoresProvider>();

    /// Variáveis Gerais
    Map<String, int> estadosMotores = estadoMotoresProvider.estadoMotores;
    double larguraGeral = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    /// Campos no centro do gráfico
    String infoEstadoMotores = '';
    String infoQtdMotores = '';

    List estados = [
      "Desligados",
      "Ligados",
      "Defeitos",
      "Manutenção",
    ];

    List<Color> cores = [
      const Color.fromRGBO(97, 97, 97, 1),
      const Color.fromRGBO(73, 155, 25, 1),
      const Color.fromRGBO(153, 17, 17, 1),
      const Color.fromRGBO(16, 101, 141, 1),
    ];

    /// Retorna o Componente do Gráfico e do texto
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        /// titulo do componente
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder:
                (BuildContext internalContext, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              //
              /// Corpo do titulo
              var corpo = <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Gráfico Geral - Motores',
                    style: titulo3Branco,
                  ),
                ),
              ];

              /// Caso não seja a página dos motores e esteja em um intervalo de
              /// tamanho específico, não exibe o botão de direcionamento (overflow)
              if (paginaAtual != Telas.motores &&
                  ((larguraGeral > 900) || (larguraGeral < 770))) {
                /// adiciona o botao ao corpo do título
                corpo.add(
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      /// Navegação
                      setState(() {
                        Nagevagacao().navegar(context, Telas.motores);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }

              /// retorno do titulo do componente de acordo com tamanho e página
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 1.4,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: (paginaAtual == Telas.motores)
                      ? MainAxisAlignment.start
                      : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  //? -----
                  children: corpo,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),

        /// Gráfico
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1900) ? 2 : 1.5,
              child: Center(
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (internalContext, constraints) {
                    /// Altura e largura disponíveis
                    double altura = constraints.maxHeight;
                    double largura = constraints.maxWidth;

                    /// Estados Existentes dos Motores (apenas keys)
                    List estadosExistentes = [];

                    for (var key in estadosMotores.keys) {
                      estadosExistentes.add(key);
                    }

                    /// Texto central de acordo com a seção tocada pelo usuário
                    secaoTocada(index) {
                      /// nao tocou retorna -1
                      if (index < 0) {
                        return;
                      } else {
                        /// Exibe o texto central de acordo com a seção tocada
                        if (estadosExistentes.length == 1) {
                          // index = 0;
                        }
                        infoEstadoMotores = estadosExistentes[index];
                        infoQtdMotores =
                            "${estadosMotores[estadosExistentes[index]]}";
                      }
                    }

                    /// Carrega os dados iniciais do gráfico 
                    loadDadosMotores() {
                      /// Define um texto inicial
                      secaoTocada(index);

                      /// Total de motores nos silos
                      int total = dadosMotores.dadosMotor.length;

                      /// Lista de seções do gráfico
                      List<PieChartSectionData> listaSections = [];

                      /// Retorna uma Lista de acordo a quantidade de estados
                      listaSections = List.generate(
                        estados.length,
                        (i) {
                          /// seção tocada
                          final bool escolhido =
                              estadosExistentes.indexOf(estados[i]) == index;
    
                          /// visual da seção tocada de acordo com altura e largura
                          final double radius =
                              (escolhido) ? altura * 0.18 : altura * 0.15;

                          double porcento = 0.0;

                          /// quantidade de motores do determinado estado convertido para porcentagem
                          if (estadosExistentes.contains(estados[i])) {
                            if (estadosMotores[estados[i]]! > 0) {
                              porcento =
                                  (estadosMotores[estados[i]]! / total) * 100;
                            } else {
                              porcento = 0.0;
                            }
                          } else {
                            porcento = 0.0;
                          }

                          /// Retorno da lista de dados para construção do gráfico
                          return PieChartSectionData(
                            color: cores[i],
                            value: porcento,
                            title:
                                '${porcento.toStringAsFixed(0)}%', // Exibindo como inteiro
                            radius: radius,
                            titleStyle: titulo3Branco,
                          );
                        },
                      );

                      return listaSections;
                    }

                    /// Construção do gráfico dos motores 
                    graficoMotores() {
                      return Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          /// Gráfico
                          PieChart(
                            PieChartData(
                              centerSpaceRadius: largura / 6,
                              sectionsSpace: 0,

                              ///
                              sections: loadDadosMotores(),
                              pieTouchData: PieTouchData(
                                enabled: true,
                                touchCallback: (event, pieTouchResponse) {
                                  if (!event.isInterestedForInteractions ||
                                      pieTouchResponse == null ||
                                      pieTouchResponse.touchedSection == null) {
                                    return;
                                  } else {
                                    /// Define a seção tocada
                                    int touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse
                                        .touchedSection!.touchedSectionIndex;

                                    /// Caso seja no gráfico
                                    if (touchedIndex >= 0) {
                                      //; print(touchedIndex);
                                      setState(() {
                                        index = touchedIndex;
                                        secaoTocada(index);
                                      });
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //
                          /// Texto central
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                infoEstadoMotores,
                                style: titulo3Branco,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                infoQtdMotores,
                                style: titulo3Branco,
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    }

                    semDados() {
                      /// Dados não carregados
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: largura,
                        height: altura,
                        child: const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                    /// Variáveis de validação
                    int qtdMotores = dadosMotores.dadosMotor.length;
                    int totalMotores = 0;

                    for (var valor in estadosMotores.values) {
                      totalMotores += valor;
                    }

                    /// Dados carregados
                    if (qtdMotores > 0 && totalMotores == qtdMotores) {
                      return Container(
                        // * ------
                        child: graficoMotores(),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        // * ------
                        child: semDados(),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é que, quando o gráfico possui dois estados iniciais, tudo fica normal, funcionando como deve.
[Imagem 1 - 2 Estados Iniciais](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwGFi.png)

Quando todos os motores possuem o mesmo estado, tudo também funciona como deveria.
[Imagem 2 - 1 Estado, depois de 2 estados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFuW2.png)

Contudo, quando algum motor passa a ter outro estado, o gráfico sobrescreve a cor preta sobre as seções.
[Imagem 3 - 2 Estados, depois de 1 estado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1J2G.png)

Quando troco de página, o gráfico volta ao normal.
[Imagem 4 - Página dos Motores, 2 Estados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enCOc.png)

Eu não sei mais o que fazer, preciso de ajuda. Caso precise de mais informações ou partes do código, eu informo.

Comment: Consegui resolver de forma momentânea, aplicado um reset nos valores do gráfico, caso o tamanho anterior da lista de estados disponíveis seja 1 e novo tamanho seja 2 ou mais, causando um CircularProgressIndicator, e recriando o gráfico em seguida.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.